# Siddhi Google Pub/Sub: acknowledge message only if Siddhi app execution for event succeeds

Tags: siddhi

we are using the Google Pub/Sub extension as source for our Siddhi application. The plugin directly acknowledges the reception of a message containing the event data.

Hence, if processing of the message within the Siddhi app fails, it is acknowledged and not moved back to the topic.

Do you know if there is a way to ack. the message iff the flow through the Siddhi app succeeds?

Thanks a lot!

Cheers,
Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

I believe acknowledgment should come after consuming the event in https://github.com/siddhi-io/siddhi-io-googlepubsub/blame/master/component/src/main/java/io/siddhi/extension/io/googlepubsub/source/GooglePubSubMessageReceiver.java#L60.

Please send a PR with the fix if possible so that the Siddhi maintainers can check and merge the fix tracked under https://github.com/siddhi-io/siddhi-io-googlepubsub/issues/21

Comment: Hi Chiran, thx for you response. The issue is that the ack. is performed even if the executing the stream fails, since no exception is thrown by the method sourceEventListener.onEvent, i.e. moving the ack. after this method call makes no difference.

Comment: Hmmm, interesting. Shall we try configuring on-error (for reference https://siddhi.io/en/v5.1/docs/guides/fault-tolerance/guide/) and fix the event being ignored. Anyway, if we did not acknowledge it; we'll end up consuming the same event and failing again and again, wouldn't it.

Comment: I implemented it in a way that I only send the ack. when the stream succeeds. Therefore, I extended the Google PubSub with a new sink that sends the ack. messages. This only works if the stream is short running as it blocks GCP resources. I configured the GCP subscription that there are not more than 3 delivery attempts and that the message is sent to a dead letter topic after the 3rd attempt. I configured also a fault stream as u suggested that sends a "nack" if the stream fails.

I have one question, is a stream also failing if an aggregation where it stores its data in fails?